# Python 3.10 pattern matching (PEP 634) - wildcard in string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pattern-matching, python-3.10

I got a large list of JSON objects that I want to parse depending on the start of one of the keys, and just wildcard the rest. A lot of the keys are similar, like `"matchme-foo"` and `"matchme-bar"`. There is a builtin wildcard, but it is only used for whole values, kinda like an `else`.

I might be overlooking something but I can't find a solution anywhere in the proposal:

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching

Also a bit more about it in PEP-636:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#going-to-the-cloud-mappings

My data looks like this:

```
data = [{
          "id"     : "matchme-foo",
          "message": "hallo this is a message",
      },{
          "id"     : "matchme-bar",
          "message": "goodbye",
      },{
          "id"     : "anotherid",
          "message": "completely diffrent event"
      }, ...]
```

I want to do something that can match the id without having to make a long list of `|`'s.

Something like this:

```
for event in data:
    match event:
        case {'id':'matchme-*'}: # Match all 'matchme-' no matter what comes next
            log.INFO(event['message'])
        case {'id':'anotherid'}:
            log.ERROR(event['message'])
```

It's a relatively new addition to Python so there aren't many guides on how to use it yet.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use a ***guard***.

```
for event in data:
    match event:
        case {'id': x} if x.startswith("matchme"): # guard
            print(event["message"])
        case {'id':'anotherid'}:
            print(event["message"])
```

Quoting from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#guard):

> ***Guard***
>
> We can add an `if` clause to a pattern, known as a “*guard*”. *If the
> guard is *`false`*, match goes on to try the next `case` block*. Note that
> value capture happens before the guard is evaluated:
>
> ```
> match point:
>      case Point(x, y) if x == y:
>          print(f"The point is located on the diagonal Y=X at {x}.")
>      case Point(x, y):
>          print(f"Point is not on the diagonal.")
> ```

See also:

- [PEP 622 - Guards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#id8)
- [PEP 636 - Adding conditions to patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns)
- [PEP 634 - Guards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#id1)