# Structural pattern matching for list of unknown length in Python 3.10

Tags: python, match

Let's assume I have the following function:

```
def sum_ints(my_list: list[int]) -> int:
    return sum(my_list)
```

Before I start adding the elements in `my_list`, I want to check the type of all elements using the new `match` statement.

If `my_list` has a length of 2 for example, I can do:

```
def sum_ints(my_list: list[int]) -> int:
    match my_list:
        case [int(), int()]:
            return sum(my_list)
        case _:
            raise Exception("...")
```

How can I match the case for a list with `n` elements?

Comment: Did you mean `if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in my_list)`? Why do you need a match statement?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM This example was for the sake of simplicity as to understand if there's a `match` equivalent to achieve this. If I wanted to know an alternative, I would've reformulated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in your case you only need `all` built-in function.

```
if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in my_list):
    # Do Something
else:
    # raise Exception("...")
```

But if you **really really** want to try this logic via `match` statement you have to capture the elements first and use *match guard* to verify the condition, but it's kind of a complicated/unreadable solution in this case.

```
a = [1, 2]
match a:
    case [*elements] if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in elements):
        print("All elements are int")
    case _:
        raise Exception("Elements are not int")
```

See Also:

- [Python 3.10 pattern matching (PEP 634) - wildcard in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70111401/python-3-10-pattern-matching-pep-634-wildcard-in-string/70111451#70111451)

Comment: To me it doesn't look unreadable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion instead of iterating over the sequence twice.

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3.0]
ints    = [1, 2, 3]


def sum_ints(l: list[int]) -> int:
    match l:
        case [int()]:
            return l[0]
        case [int(), *_]:
            return l[0] + sum_ints(l[1:])
        case [x, *_]:
            raise ValueError(f'{x} is {type(x)}')


print(sum_ints(ints))
try:
    print(sum_ints(numbers))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

But since python is duck-typed some may question why one would care if an element is an `int`, `float` or whatever.